# Apache Spark Task Failure

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

Why do Apache Spark tasks fail? I thought, due to the DAG, that even without caching Tasks were recomputable? I am in fact caching, and I either get a `filenotfoundexception` or the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 9238.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 9238.0 (TID 17337, ip-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute.internal): java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_299_piece0 of broadcast_299
    org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:930)
    org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:155)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
    org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:160)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It's very bizarre because I have run the same program on smaller instances and I don't get the `filenotfoundexception - no space left on this device`, instead I get the above error. When I say, double the instance size, it tells me there's no space left on the device after about 1 hour of working - same program, bigger memory and it runs out of space! What gives?

Comment: you are trying to run a DecisionTree classification algorithm?

Comment: No. Gradient descent, if that helps

Comment: if you try to check the source code, there is 9 points where spark issues `filenotfoundexception` and here you have a different issue...

Comment: Yes this time the tasks just failed. I have run the program maybe 3000 times, and since yesterday I have started either getting the above error or `filenotfoundexception - no space left on this device`.

Comment: can you update your question with the result of `df`command. I suspect that you don't have enough temporary memory left on your device.

Comment: Sorry I have closed the cluster - as when I re-start it the same error appears almost immediately. Doesn't the Spark `ContextCleaner` keep the temporary space clean?

Comment: Yes but maybe you are using up all the tmpfs disk size each time. On some systems, /tmp/ is an in-memory tmpfs file system, with its own size limit. It's possible that this limit has been exceeded.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can I increase it? It wasn't happening consistently until I increased the number of partitions (60 partitions for 20 cores).

Comment: well actually yes, you can increase your inodes number or descrease partitions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned in [SPARK-751](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-751) issue :

> Right now on each machine, we create M * R temporary files for
>   shuffle, where M = number of map tasks, R = number of reduce tasks.
>   This can be pretty high when there are lots of mappers and reducers
>   (e.g. 1k map * 1k reduce = 1 million files for a single shuffle). The
>   high number can cripple the file system and significantly slow the
>   system down. We should cut this number down to O(R) instead of O(M*R).

So if you indeed see that your disks are running out of inodes, You can try the following to fix the problem:

1. Decrease partitions (see coalesce with shuffle = false).
2. You can also try to drop the number of partitions to O(R) by “[consolidating files](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12637642/Consolidating%20Shuffle%20Files%20in%20Spark.pdf)” since file-systems behave differently.
3. Sometimes you may simply find that you need your system administrator to increase the number of inodes the FS supports.

Comment: Thank you. `conf.set("spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles", "true")` does not seem to help. I guess I'll just cut down the partitions; but I do feel that will affect performance (I read to use 3 partitions for every core for optimal performance).

Comment: You'll need to find your own balance between performance and scalability. Or you can the 3rd approach.